# jquery toggle + binding and unbinding hover

Tags: jquery, click, hover, toggle, bind

hey folks. having a bit of an issue using

```
 .toggle()
```

As of right now, I can successfully hover over a div and show a separate div and then hover out and hide it.  The click is also working and it unbinds the hover correctly.

Where I'm having trouble is on an 'unclick' hiding the div and re-enabling the hover.

Here's the code:

```
$('#song1').hover(
    function() { $('#song1_selected').fadeIn(); },
    function() { $('#song1_selected').fadeOut(); }   
  );

$('#song1').click(function() {
    $('#song1_selected').show();
    $("#song1").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
  });
```

any help is apprecaited!!

thanks, matt

Comment: When should the div be hidden? When you click anywhere else on the side?

Comment: the div should be hidden on every other click... 2,4, etc.

Comment: @MattNathanson: What have you tried with `toggle`? That is what the function is for.

Comment: yeah, that's where i'm having trouble implementing it.. can't seem to get it to work! stupid me.

Comment: @MattNathanson: Yes, but what exactly does not work? Where are you stuck? The documentation provides an example: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: what do you mean by an "unclick"?  Do you mean "mouseup" or on a second click?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dynamically creating elements, `.click()` and all the normal handlers won't work.

You need to bind the events using `.live()`:

```
$('#song1').live('click', function() {
  ...
```

Comment: @DavidHobs: I wrote this answer six months before `.on()` was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

How about just setting a flag on each click and checking it when you want to fade in/out, instead of binding/unbinding ?

```
$('#song1').hover(
    function() {
        if ( ! $(this).data('activesong') ) {
           $('#song1_selected').stop().fadeIn();
        }
    },
    function() {
       if ( ! $(this).data('activesong') ) {
           $('#song1_selected').stop().fadeOut();
       }
    }    
);

$('#song1').click(
    function() {
        var isActive = !$(this).data('activesong');
       $('#song1_selected').toggle(isActive);
       $("#song1").data('activesong', isActive);
   }
);
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qTprn/